# Why can I not sculpt or grid fill from this face?

Tags: bezier-curves, edges, subdivision-surface, extrude, sculpt

I am hoping to sculpt this leg shape, but I can't seem to create clean geometry to do so. I can do an alt-f type fill but it is messy. [image]
Grid fill isn't working.
Thank you so much!
[image]

Comment: Do you want to have it flat or 3D? If you want to create a 3D model from the shape I would start with 2 cylinders, join them and do a remesh. Then you can sculpt it as you like. If you want to create a flat shape, then start with a plane and use the Knife tool. Try to create a quads topology. You can add thickness with the Solidify modifier or just by extruding the mesh.